# How to open port 1973+ on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vps

Hello I would like to know how to open some ports, i already opened port 80 using this

`tcp: 1-65535; udp: 1-65535`

But I only managed to get some ports open, the ports I really need are:
1656, 1971, 1973, 1975, 1976, 1977

If someone could tell me which method to use, I would greatly appreciate

Comment: Where do you need the ports opened? On the box itself? In the network settings?